# application which printed a document

Tags: windows, api, printing, spool

I am developing a program in c ++ that manages all documents are sent to the printers in my company. I am using the windows spool api to capture information about the jobs that are sent to the printers. I need to capture some information about which application printed a job (Word, Libre Office, etc). Does anyone know if it´s possible to obtain this information by any function of the spool or through another dll that gives me this information?

Answer (score 0):

If you could figure out the ID or handle of the thread that's doing the printing, you could trace that back to the process, and then probably get the executable name.

But I don't see anything in EnumJobs or document events that gives you anything useful (beyond the username), so I don't think it's possible through normal APIs.

With Detours, or perhaps some hook, you might be able to do this, but I don't have any details.